# If $f^3=\rm id$ then it is identity function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f^3(x)=f\circ f\circ f(x)=x$ for all $x$.

How can I prove $f$ is the identity function?

Comment: To begin, $f$ must be monotone and $f^{-1} = f \circ f$, so $f$ must be strictly increasing.

Comment: @HansEngler: Thank you. Could you explain a little more please?

Comment: Expanding Hans Engler's comment: Show that $f$ must be injective and surjective, then $f$ is increasing or decreasing by continuity, thus $f\circ f$ is increasing, thus $f^{-1}$ is increasing.

Comment: Show injective by contradiction. If $f(x) = f(x')$ then $f^3(x) = f^3(x')$ so either $f^3(x) \neq x $ or $f^3(x') \neq x'$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, if $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = f(y)$ then $x = f(f(f(x))) = f(f(f(y))) = y$ so $f$ is injective thus everywhere monotone, either increasing or decreasing. 
This latter fact relies on continuity: given $x,x',x'' \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x'' > x' > x$ and $f(x) >f(x'') >  f(x')$, say (so that it is not everywhere decreasing somewhere) in the decreasing case, then by intermediate value theorem there would be an $a \in [x,x']$ such that $f(a) = f(x'')$, an obvious contradiction. Then look at the set $\{x,f(x),f(f(x))\}$.  If $f$ is increasing, $x \leq f(x) \leq f(f(x))$, and if $f$ is decreasing, $x \geq f(x) \geq f(f(x))$.  In either case, the argument is the same: because $f$ is increasing in the first case, say, we have necessarily by applying $f$ to each part of the inequality, $f(x) \leq f(f(x)) \leq f(f(f(x))) = x \leq f(x)$.  This is only possible if $f(x) = x$ (the same trick works when $f$ is decreasing).  Since $x$ was arbitrary, you're done.

Answer (score 4):

First show that $f^{-1}$ is strictly increasing. The comments above give hints how to show this. (You note that $f^{-1}=f^2$, hence $f$ is strictly monotone by continuity, hence $f^{-1}$ is strictly increasing). Since $f^{-1}$ is strictly increasing it follows that $f$ is strictly increasing.

Now assume that $f(x)>x$ some $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f^2(x)>f(x)$, implying that $f^3(x)>f^2(x)$, hence $f^3(x)>f^2(x)>f(x)>x$. A contradiction.